# How to update multiple tables by single mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables tb1 & tb2
I have to update a common column of both tables, i.e user_level
I have a common criteria for both tables like username.

So I want to update like this:

```
UPDATE tb1, tb2 SET user_level=1 WHERE username="Mr.X"
```

But somehow it is not working.
What would be the correct mysql query for this?

Comment: When you say database you really mean database or table?

Comment: No, I said it mistakenly. Those would be tables. I updated my question

Comment: It is showing: Column 'user_level' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I want to use Like this: UPDATE tb1,tb2 SET tb1.user_level=1, tb2.user_level=1 WHERE username="Mr.X" Is it right query?

Comment: but username has to come from either tb1 or tb2 and you probably want another condition. Try `WHERE tb1.username = "Mr.X" AND tb2.username = "Mr.X"`

Comment: If you don't add a second condition, all rows in one of the table will be updated which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You are doing a join by specifying 2 tables, so personally I would just run 2 separate `UPDATE` statements if you don't care for joins. It's also easier to read that way.

Comment: UPDATE tb1,tb2 SET tb1.user_level=1, tb2.user_level=1 WHERE username="Mr.X" AND tb1.username=tb2.username. is it correct?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_1 tb1, 
       table_2 tb2, 
       table_3 tb3 
SET    tb1.field2 = "some value", 
       tb2.field3 = "some other value", 
       tb3.field4 = "some another value" 
WHERE  tb1.field1 = tb2.field1 
       AND tb1.field1 = tb3.field1 
       AND tb1.field1 = "value"
```

I tested the code on MSAccess and SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Try to format your code better in the future. I took care of it this time. Also try to add an explanation, a code block alone might not help anybody who is looking for an answer to the question in the future.

Comment: This works perfectly. I have a tendency to use AS, e.g. table_1 AS tb1, etc. This also works with MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is solved,just follow this what I have done-

create table tb1(user_level int);
create table tb2(user_level int,username varchar(20));

insert into tb1 values(2);
insert into tb2 values(2,'Mr.X');

I have this two tables like this where user_level is common,now according to you I tried to update the user_level column in both table using one query on a common criteria for both table i.e. username.

I tried to update the value of user_level column from 2 to 3 in both tables where the username is 'Mr.X' using a single query,so I tried the following query and it perfectly worked..

```
          update tb1 inner join tb2

          on tb1.user_level=tb2.user_level 

              set tb1.user_level=3,

                  tb2.user_level=3

             where tb2.username='Mr.X' ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
update db1 inner join db2 on db1.username = db2.username 
   set db1.user_level = 1,
       db2.user_level = 1
  where db1.username = 'a';
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba34ac/1

Comment: I don't want to use inner join in this case

Comment: update db1,db2  
   set db1.user_level = 1,
       db2.user_level = 1
  where db1.username = 'a' and db1.username = db2.username;

Comment: Tin Tran are you sure your code is ok? I am asking because a little mistake can cause serious security issue of my site while implementing the code. If it is ok and correct I think it is the best and simplified code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is that you have to specify the full table and row/column you are trying to update in the two tables and indeed database if you are updating across databases too.

typical example:

```
UPDATE tb1, tb2 SET tb1.username = '$username', tb2.location ='New York'WHERE tb1.userid = '$id' AND tb2.logid = '$logid'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can update it without join  like this

```
UPDATE table1 T1, table2 T2 
SET T1.status = 1 ,T2.status = 1 
WHERE T1.id = T2.tab1_id and T1.id = 1
```

We can update it with join like this

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER join table2 on table1.id=table2.tab1_id 
SET table1.status=3,table2.status=3
WHERE table1.id=1
```